# HTML textarea with HTML support?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I want html tag support in html textarea in my form like in stackoverflow when asking question. and pass its value in php and print exact user type in textarea.

so how can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried? There are numerous tutorials and snippets for this if you just google it. Also, there are open-source files for it.

Comment: Ha ha, LOL so many things to do something like that. Start by Googling tinymce.

Comment: -1 you have obviously not done any research whatsoever. You need to at least attempt to solve your own problem before asking here.

Comment: tinymce and ckeditor have lots of option and i want only some and they are to big to use only cause i only want in only one textarea thas why i am asking is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: sorry guys and yes i dont research or googling cause i was busy that's why i just ask here to get help soon and now i am using nicEdit it's very simple. thnx all of you

Comment: so what Stack Overflow is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Tinymce or ckeditor.

http://ckeditor.com/

http://www.tinymce.com/

And there are many more wysiwyg editor available.

http://phphtmledit.com/ Cute Editor for PHP

http://nicedit.com/

do some Googling and you will find many more.

Good Luck

Comment: And so the cop-out is the accepted answer. I expected nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Use CKEditor at http://www.ckeditor.com

Using jQuery it can easily turn textareas into WYSIWYG HTMLareas.

Comment: This is more of a comment to the question than an answer to the question. Are there perhaps more details you could provide, like an example? If not, then consider deleting this and posting as a comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you need to get a clear idea of what you are trying to do. Judging by the sorry state of your question, I'd wager you have no clue what you're doing, you're way out of your depth and you're asking us how to dive.

I'm sure you've noticed that StackOverflow presents its preview instantaneously. I can hold down a button and it will update with absolutely no perceivable delay. This is a tell-tale sign that PHP is NOT involved, it is all done through the "magic" of JavaScript.

Getting the contents of a textarea and previewing it as HTML is a simple as:

```
document.getElementId('preview').innerHTML = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
```

But SO does not do something this primitive, it implements the entire Markdown setup that the server-side uses to show you EXACTLY what will come out of the other end.

All in all, it's actually pretty complicated and you really should start off with easier exercises, look up some tutorials, or just jump on the bandwagon and cop out by using jQuery.